# What is the correct choice for this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The next Olympic Games (will be - is) in London.

I chose "is" as it is something scheduled, but my teacher told me the correct answer is will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible.

"Will be" is more normal in this context, I think - just talking about an event which is expected to happen. I would only use "is" in restricted contexts - talking specifically about the planning, or about the Olympic games in general.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated example. "Olympic Games" will give trouble even to native speakers, because it can be understood as plural or singular. Generally in English writing you'll want to interpret a noun ending in "s" as plural (there are exceptions). Here it seems like your teacher is considering it in the plural so you'd want to go with "will be" for the future tense. You could use "is" in the future tense only for singular concepts.

In colloquial speech "is" would be understood, but it probably will strike a native speaker as off.

For example:

Both of the following sentences are correct because "meeting" is singular.

The next meeting will be in London **OR** The next meeting is in London.

However we see the plural is different:

The next meetings will be in London **NOT** The next meetings is in London.

The first sentence above is correct, because "meetings" is plural. The second is NOT correct for the same reason. To construct the sentence in that way you would have to change "is" to "are":

The next meetings are in London.